# Face Detector Parameters for OpenCV cv_haar_scale_image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

What does cv_haar_scale_image do in opencv's function cvhaardetectobjects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag `CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE`, tells the algorithm to scale the image rather than the detector.

There is an example of its use here: [Face detection: How to find faces with openCV](http://www.xavigimenez.net/blog/2010/02/face-detection-how-to-find-faces-with-opencv/)

Answer (score 5):

**It enables more optimization.**

The face detect implementation is optimized for CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE more than CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING.

Because CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE method is more DMA (direct memory access) friendly. Default method (CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING) implementation needs random access to main memory area widely.

Comment: I read that on some website, but that explanation still is not clear. What exactly does it do? To optimize what are the tradeoffs? Also I beileve 0 does nothing, no canny pruning.

Answer (score 3):

According to EMGU, which is an .NET wrapper for OpenCV, and sometimes has way better documentation than OpenCV,

> DO_CANNY_PRUNING
>   If it is set, the function uses Canny edge detector
>   to reject some image regions that contain too few or too much edges
>   and thus can not contain the searched object. The particular threshold
>   values are tuned for face detection and in this case the pruning
>   speeds up the processing
>
> SCALE_IMAGE
>   For each scale factor used the function will downscale
>   the image rather than "zoom" the feature coordinates in the classifier
>   cascade. Currently, the option can only be used alone, i.e. the flag
>   can not be set together with the others
>
> FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
>   If it is set, the function finds the largest
>   object (if any) in the image. That is, the output sequence will
>   contain one (or zero) element(s)
>
> DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
>   It should be used only when
>   CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT is set and min_neighbors > 0. If the flag
>   is set, the function does not look for candidates of a smaller size as
>   soon as it has found the object (with enough neighbor candidates) at
>   the current scale. Typically, when min_neighbors is fixed, the mode
>   yields less accurate (a bit larger) object rectangle than the regular
>   single-object mode (flags=CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT), but it is much
>   faster, up to an order of magnitude. A greater value of min_neighbors may be specified to improve the accuracy.

[Source](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/e2278977-87ea-8fa9-b78e-0e52cfe6406a.htm)

Answer (score 0):

CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING causes flat regions that have no lines to be skipped by the classifier