# What is causing the "Camera dropped frame!" error when running detectMultiScale using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a function that gets called from main in a for loop that searches for faces from a video feed. The code runs perfectly in the first run through, but on the second loop it outputs many "Camera dropped frame!" errors to the console and no longer updates the video feed.

I have found the line that causes the erros, it is the one that contains the detectMultiScale function in it. The full function is here:

```
void findInFrame(Mat inputFrame)
{
    vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat grayFrame;

    cvtColor(inputFrame, grayFrame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    faceClassifier.detectMultiScale( grayFrame, faces);


    for(int i=0;i<faces.size();i++)
    {
        Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
        ellipse(inputFrame,center,Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

        Mat faceROI = grayFrame(faces[i]);
    }
    imshow("frame", inputFrame);
}
```

The line that throws the error is:

```
faceClassifier.detectMultiScale( grayFrame, faces);
```

Every frame after the first causes the errors. How can i fix this?

Main is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

string faceHaar = "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
string eyesHaar = "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml";

CascadeClassifier faceClassifier;
void findInFrame(Mat inputFrame);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    VideoCapture cam(0);
    Mat frame;

    if(!faceClassifier.load(faceHaar))
    {
        cout << "Error loading face cascade" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        cam >> frame;

        if(!frame.empty())
        {
            findInFrame(frame);
            usleep(1000);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "frame empty" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specify the function a bit more - I feel like its just taking too long to process your matches.

```
faceClassifier.detectMultiScale(grayFrame, faces, 1.3, 3,0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(20, 30));
```

Where `size` is the size you trained your detector, 1.3 is a scale threshold and 3 is how many nearest neighbours are needed for a match.

Aside from that, dropping frames isn't a huge issue, but you could well be doing some things wrong elsewhere in your code, like where you grab your new frame.

I also would consider changing the function to `void findInFrame(Mat &inputFrame)` and calling imshow in your main loop, not in the function. Note that the &inputFrame isn't really a conventional pointer and doesn't require you to change how you reference inputFrame in the function

Comment: Thanks heaps for your response, how can I find which library the CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE constant is in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119772/face-detector-parameters-for-opencv-cv-haar-scale-image

ive added another suggestion in answer

Comment: I think maybe CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE has been deprecated and replaced with CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE. I replaced it with that but still get the same issue. Gonna update the question with my main to make sure I'm not grabbing frames incorrectly.

Comment: let me know if it works/doesnt help. I think my last suggestion would help the most.

Comment: Ended up adding the cam >> frame line into the detectAndDisplay function itself and for some reason it now works.

Also, strangely enough, I also need to have a cam>>frame line in the main function in the for loop just before the detectAndDisplay function is called. This is definitely not ideal and makes the video feed extremely slow (looks like 10fps), but I can't get it working otherwise. Thanks heaps for your help chris! I plan to explore what is going on here